# socket.io server not listening

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io

I'm using node.js and socket.io for a simple app. My browser is receiving data from server nicely but server not receiving from client(browser). May be the event listener for client_data not working. Here is the server:

```
var http = require("http");
var url = require("url");
var io = require('socket.io');

function start(route) {
  function onRequest(request, response) {
    var pathname = url.parse(request.url).pathname;
    console.log("Request for " + pathname + " received.");
    route(pathname, response);
  }
  var server = http.createServer(onRequest);
  server.listen(8888);
  var server_io = io.listen(server);
  server_io.on('connection', function(socket){
     //send data to client
    setInterval(function(){
        socket.emit('date', {'date': new Date()});
    }, 1000);
  });
  //recieve client data
  server_io.on('client_data', function(data){ //May be it is not listening
    process.stdout.write(data.letter); // not working
    //console.log(data.letter); not working
  });
  console.log("Server has started.");
}

exports.start = start;
```

Client code:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script>
      var socket = io.connect();
    socket.on('date', function(data){
    document.getElementById("date").innerHTML = data.date;
    });

    function sendKey(e){
      socket.emit('client_data', {'letter': String.fromCharCode(e.charCode)});
    }
    </script>
    <div id="date">This is our socket.html file</div>
    <textarea id="text" onKeyPress="sendKey(event)"></textarea>
  </body>
</html>
```

What is the problem with my server code?

Answer (score 1):

This error occurs because `.on('client_data')` must be binded to `socket`, not `server_io`. The code may look like the following:

```
server_io.on('connection', function(socket){
  setInterval(function(){
    socket.emit('date', {'date': new Date()});
  }, 1000);
  socket.on('client_data', function(data){
    process.stdout.write(data.letter);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`server_io` only recieves `connection` events. The `client_data` event sent from the client is heard by the `socket` object passed into the `connection` callback, not the `server_io` object.

You need to use `socket.on("client_data", ...);` and move that code into your `connection` callback.

That `socket` object is connected to a particular client web page instance, and it recieves messages only sent by that page. Each time a new client page connects, a new `socket` object is created and passed as an argument into the `connection` handler function.